# child height div expand to bottom of parent div

Tags: javascript, css, html, height

I have the following html:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div1a"></div>
    <div class="div1b"></div>
    <div class="div1c"></div>
</div>
```

Here a link of layout: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGaG/5/

I need to give height only to div1.

- div1a and div1b have fixed height. (In fact div1 has also a fixed height)
- div1c needs to expand to the bottom of div1.

For example:

div1:    400px
div1a: 100px
div1b: 100px
div1c:  50px

So there is 150px empty place at the bottom. (400 - 100 - 100 - 50 = 150). How can I solve this with css that div1c has the height to the bottom of div1?

If I do `height:100%` for div1c, then it takes height of div1, and that is 400px.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you try height:auto; for div1c

Comment: @Rohan Then, it takes the height of itself (50px)

Comment: And you can't set div1c's height to 200px for some reason? Will div1's height change ever?

Comment: @Zach I think you didn't understand me very well. I can't set it. Because div1 should be dynamic (400px is not fixed). It can be different. then div1c should always expand to the bottom of parent div (so div1c also can not be a fixed value)

Comment: @Ozkan, my bad! Are these heights being set dynamically with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes indeed. I need to give height to parent div via javascript

Comment: @Ozkan: I'm all for CSS purism, but if you use JavaScript to set the height of div1, then you can use JavaScript to set the height of div1c as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.div1 { height: 400px; }
.div1a { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both; }
.div1b { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;    
    clear: both; }
.div1c { height: 100%; }
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/ENaqK/

Comment: Hmm, how exactly is this hacky? It's just using the property of floats.

Comment: float left means a div must be aside the above div. But here we have all the divs vertically

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I'd say it's more clever than hacky ;)

Comment: I tried to add scrolling and it broke: http://jsfiddle.net/r8qtp7wu/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the default block layouting, you could use a Flex layout and then use `flex-grow` to indicate that the last element should grow:

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.div1c {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some CSS that will do it.

`.div1` is `overflow: hidden` set to grab the height of the tallest div. Which it sounds like it could be `.div1a` or `.div1b`. `.div1c` is `position: absolute` so that it can use `.div1` is a guide, it positions itself off of the `bottom` and is put into position with `top` and `right`.

```
.div1 {
    width: 450px;
    position: relative;
    background: wheat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div1a {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
.div1b {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
}
.div1c {
    width: 150px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 150px;
    background: pink;
}
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/7ZGaG/

Comment: Hi @nheinrich. The layout you have is different. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGaG/5/ Here you can see it, and also my problem too. So the pink div should expand to parent div, but how?

Comment: ahh, I thought you were going for columns.

Comment: You could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/7ZGaG/6/. But honestly it's pretty hacky.

Comment: No no, i can't give a fixed height to div1c. Because div1 (the parent) should not have a fixed height neither

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with ([my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachdunn/exERj/)):

```
.div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.div1a {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.div1b {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.div1c {
    position: relative;
    top: 200;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I would do it a bit differently, however, if I had access to JavaScript.

Comment: See my main post please for the template i have. the layout is vertical without floating

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be to style the parent `div` with `overflow:hidden` and the child `div` with `height:100%`

Add the following attributes:

---

For `div1`

`position:fixed`

---

For `div1c`

`overflow:hidden;`
    `position:relative;`
   `height:100%;`

---

Sample code - http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGaG/26/

Comment: Sample code relevant to the question would be helpful (interesting answer, by the way).